# cURL having issues handling URL source with colons

Tags: php, curl

Got a php script using cURL grabbing the contents of a url that has colons in the source name:

```
$url = 'http://www.awebsite.com/anxml:file:thatoddly:hascolons:allovertheplace:';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if(curl_errno($ch)) {
   echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

I am getting the error.

```
Could not resolve host: http; nodename nor servname provided, or not known <url here>
```

I've double checked that the url is working fine otherwise, but I suspect cURL is choking on the colons in the filename.  The source isn't mine, so I can't remove the colons.

Is there another way around this?

Comment: The URL is not "working" you get 404 "Not found".

Comment: The url in my question is contrived and for illustrative purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--data-urlencode), **cURL** has a *--data-urlencode* flag.

If it's just one URL not being done via CLI but PHP, you could use PHP's **urlencode()**.

Comment: Thanks taco for the suggestion.  I gave it shot and I receive the following error:  Curl error: Could not resolve host: http%3A//www.awebsite.com/anxml%3Afile%3Athatoddly%3Ahascolons%3Aallovertheplace%3A; nodename nor servname provided, or not known http://www.awebsite.com/anxml:file:thatoddly:hascolons:allovertheplace:

Comment: Hey taco, yes I've tried encoding just the last part too and looks like that was the issue - happens I was getting cURL errors from misuse.  I've provided an answer to clarify it's use.

Answer (score 2):

Provider fixed their files, so I don't have to deal with colons any longer.  Turns out I was using cURL improperly after all and likely the urlencode() with the code below would have worked.

This DIDN'T WORK:

```
    $url = urlencode($url);
    $url = str_replace("http%3A","http:",$url);

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

This DID WORK:

```
    $url = urlencode($url);
    $url = str_replace("http%3A","http:",$url);

    $c = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $data = iconv("UTF-8","ISO-8859-1",curl_exec($c));
```

Hope that helps someone out.