# HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am getting the same error for this, please suggest

```
$url="http://domain.com/manage/File Name.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents
$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Comment: Did you check if `$url` need to be escaped? For instance, replace space and other characters by URI encoded equivalent

Comment: thanks a ton Edouard Lopez, adding `%20` for space in URL worked perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 6):

This error come, when your curl url contains white spaces. you have to encode url for remove white space.

```
$base_url = "http://domain.com/manage/";
$url = "File Name.xml";
$ch = curl_init();
$final_url = $base_url . curl_escape($ch, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);                
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    // get the url contents
$data = curl_exec($ch); // execute curl request
curl_close($ch);
echo $data;
```

Answer (score 3):

As describe in the comment, your URL contains not encoded characters (spaces).

### Solution

**Encode your URL** when setting `CURLOPT_URL`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode($url));
```

You could also use [`curl_escape()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-escape.php) to encode the query string part.

### References

- answer of [cURL having issues handling URL Source with colons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12231566/802365).

Comment: For me only using `urlencode($url)` backslashes and encodes even the `https://` parts so using for entire URL is not worked for me. But I got the idea

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode your URL before sending the request

```
<?php
$url=urlencode("http://domain/file name.xml");
?>
```

[urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

Comment: hi @tim i also get same error i use your code after that i got blank response

Answer (score 1):

Answers here suggest using url_encode or curl_escape functions. If you want to be RFC 3986 compliant, use [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php)() function instead. This helped with a curl request in PHP 7. Hoep it helps others.